# Select file in fixed directory path (user shouldn't be able to change folder)

Tags: asp.net

I use this so the use can browse files, but what i need is to make this happen in a fixed folder path (a path I store as a configuration).

```
<input type="file" class="col-md-6 form-control file btn btn-default" runat="server" id="fSaldos" />
```

1) Is there any parameter or some additional setting to make this happen?

2) How can this be set to use that path also first time it opens? I mean when a path is selected this keeps that path in the future but how to set it before it opens for the first time so it also works the first time (now the first time it runs it's going to a OS default folder it seems).

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot. It is up to the client.

Comment: I understand, but then how can you allow users to select a file to be proccessed in a production folder that has specific rights set for this site, a folder that's pre-configured to be the container for this files? I need them not to change this folder, i just need users to select a file. That's why i need this browser control to always open in one specific folder path.

Comment: @Jcis: If you need to control the file system then your server-side application needs to be what interacts with the file system.  Maintain your "production folder" server-side or in a network share somewhere and give your users a list of files from which to choose, rather than a file input.

Comment: @David, exactly, I already maintain the production folder server-side in a network share with specific permissions. What i realize now is this not the best control for this, maybe i should use a list and then users would select from there, good point. Thanks.